# Hive query language as analyzer component- WSO2 BAM 2.0 ALPHA

Tags: hive, wso2, alpha, analyzer, wso2-bam

With `WSO2 BAM 2.0 ALPHA`, is there any out-of-the-box analyzer component where Hive queries can be written in order to aggregate data after retrieving it from a Cassandra datastore and then included in Analyzer framework sequence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive was introduced to BAM since **BAM 2.0 ALPHA version 3**.
Now we have BAM complete released version, BAM 2.0.1.

Comment: So does BAM 2.0.1 has both analyzer sequence components and support to Hive as well ?

Comment: No. Analyzer sequence is a deprecated feature. Hive is the replaced feature. The main concern was the scalability.

Comment: Is there any way alert/notification can be supported out of box with BAM 2.0.1 ?

Comment: You can implement using a toolox if required. But not out of the box. And also best way to implement a alert/notification that should responsive quickly, should be done with WSO2 CEP. Pure BAM is not that useful as it may take a long time to fire an alert after a map-reduce job. Implementing that out-of-the box feature is there in the WSO2 BAM road map.